# Синтаксическая ошибка в JavaScript массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вставил в консоль браузера такой массив:

`[['a', 'a'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C'], ['d', 'D'], ['e', 'E'], ['f', 'F'], ['g', 'G'], ['h', 'H'], ['i', 'I'], ['j'. 'J'], ['k','K'], ['l','L'], ['m','M'], ['n', 'N'], ['o','O'], ['p', 'P'], ['q', 'Q'], ['r', 'R'], ['s', 'S'], ['t', 'T'], ['u', 'U'], ['v', 'V'], ['w', 'W'], ['x', 'X'], ['y', 'Y'], ['z', 'Z'], ['0', '0'], ['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['5', '5'], ['6', '6'], ['7', '7'], ['8', '8'], ['9', '9'], ['SPACE', 'пробел'], ['ESCAPE', 'Esc'], ['RETURN', 'Enter'], ['LEFT', 'Cтрелка влево'], ['UP', 'Стрелка вверх'], ['DOWN', 'Стрелка вниз'], ['RIGHT', 'Стрелка вправо'] ]`
Консоль выдает синтаксическую ошибку. Где именно она?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставил код и запустил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
```

**Значит где-то есть точка.**

Вставляю в редактор, делаю поиск и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо! Все работает!

Comment: @likel0vsky, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)